# File dependency in Airflow

Tags: python, shell, dependencies, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a Airflow DAG and I want to trigger it on particular day of each month. It is a table migration task so I don't want to move it unless tables in directory have been updated.

How can I do something like the DAG executes on that day only if there's some file in that directory? Or is there a better way to do it like check if files have been updated.

Please suggest me some solution and the way to do it.

Comment: Create a script that does solely this job, then use CRON to schedule it when to run.

Comment: I can think of looping in script but won't is run forever until the file comes. I am a fresher, can you tell me how do I end the task after the day is over. Is it even possible?

Comment: You make a new task which has the job to search for that file. If it founds it then it exits with code 0 (success), otherwise exists with (1). Anything else than zero means error in exit codes. The second task  runs only if the first tasks executes successfully (it found the file you talked about). To use crontab, use Google and read "how to use crontab in linux". It's extremely simple.

Comment: yes I got it. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Airflow Sensors. It is a kind of operator that will keep running until a certain criterion is met. You can use `S3KeySensor` to wait for a key to be present in an S3 bucket.

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor.html

And you can set the schedule interval to something like "0 0 1 * *" - this will schedule the DAG to run once a month at midnight on the first day of the month.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about sensors. As a matter of fact there exists a predefined  sensor called File_Sensor that does the same job. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There exists a predefined sensor called File_Sensor that checks for the file in specified directory after a particular interval called 'poke_interval' and runs once the file is found.

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor

filesensor = FileSensor(task_id= "my_file_sensor_task", poke_interval= 300, filepath="file path", run_as_user="batchid", dag=dag)
```

poke_interval is in seconds.

We can set this as upstream before the main job to accomplish the requirement.